# Extract resource images from a games APK

Tags: decryption, apk

I'm looking to pull the images off of the game "Summoners War" to use for wallpapers and such. I have access to the images themselves, but they seem to be encrypted and cannot be viewed. Looking at the image in a hex viewer shows that the png headers are missing and have been replaced.[image: screenshot of hex data]

I do have access to the sourcecode after decompiling with APKTool, but I am not entirely sure what I am looking for in order to decrypt the images. Ive looked around for anything relating to 'decrypt' but a lot of it has been dead ends with network decryption, not decryption of the asset files.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks I completely overlooked that the files were already in PNG so i was thinking in that direction. I was able to strip the first 16 bits, change the format to jpg and can view them.

Answer (score 3):

Your hex dump shows the plan-text word `JFIF`. These four letters are an indicator for an [JPEG image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), not a PNG image.

The magic bytes of a JPEG image are `FF D8 FF` which are also present in your hex dump starting at offset `0x10` which indicates that with a high probability you have a JPEG image here.